# Pandas merge or update an empty dataframe with another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty dataframe `df1`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])

df1
A   B   C   D   E
```

I want to merge or update this dataframe with another dataframe `df2`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'B': [1,2,3],
                     'D': [4,5,6],
                     'E': [7,8,9]})
df2
    B   D   E
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

to get a merged or updated dataframe as

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   NaN 1   NaN 4   7
1   NaN 2   NaN 5   8
2   NaN 3   NaN 6   9
```

Besides, efficiency is required because I have a long `df1` and `df2`.

Any good idea? Thank you.

Comment: Try this: `df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns)`

Comment: At start you are saying you have empty df1 at end you are saying its very long df1. which one is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns)
```

Output:

```
    A  B   C  D  E
0 NaN  1 NaN  4  7
1 NaN  2 NaN  5  8
2 NaN  3 NaN  6  9
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat((df1, df2))
```